# Why does (format "%x" some-large-number) produces incorrect results?

Tags: format, numbers

I wanted the hexadecimal string for a large integer such as below:

```
(format "%x" 2738188573457603759)
```

This returns `2600000000f95c00` which is incorrect, it should be `2600000000f95caf`.

The value of `most-positive-fixnum` on my box is `0x1fffffffffffffff` which is less than the number I'm supplying above.

As a user I'm a bit baffled what is happening.  The manual indicates integers larger than this range are converted to a floating-point number which is a concern for precision but I suspect this is what is biting me here?

I should have known there was an issue with this number since normally I evaluate them directly using `eval-last-sexp` and it didn't show the octal/hex variants.. :)

I wonder why Emacs Lisp doesn't support bignums, so precision would not be an issue?

Comment: `0x1fffffffffffffff` is less than `0x2600000000f95caf`, which would explain why you're getting these problems.

Comment: Wrt your last question: I've been asking for bignum support for a long time. The place to ask that is `emacs-devel@gnu.org`. The place to request it is either on that same list or via `M-x report-emacs-bug` (that's for enhancements too, not just bug reports).

Comment: For latecomers, bignum support was added in Emacs 27.1, and consequently the issue in the question no longer occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question -- you're dealing with a number which is larger than `most-positive-fixnum` and are encountering floating point precision errors as a result.  (Refer to https://floating-point-gui.de/ to understand what's going on in detail).

The usual solution in Emacs is to use `M-x calc`.  Type `d 6` in the calc buffer to run `calc-hex-radix` (or `d r` to enter any supported radix value), and then all numbers will be displayed in hex.

In this case, you can enter `2738188573457603759` and it will be displayed as `16#2600000000F95CAF`.

---

Support for bignums has since been added to Emacs (starting from 27.1), so using `calc` is no longer necessary -- the code in the question nowadays produces an accurate result.